# How to create a dynamic comment to an object?

Tags: postgresql

I want to embed variable information in a table that is created from a script. The following works:

```
SELECT( 'created ' || CURRENT_DATE ||' and is in CH1903 LV03');
```

But it seems I can't use it for creating a comment:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE public.mytable IS SELECT( 'created ' || CURRENT_DATE ||' and is in CH1903 LV03');
\set mycomment SELECT( 'created ' || CURRENT_DATE ||' and is in CH1903 LV03');
COMMENT ON TABLE public.mytable IS :mycomment;
```

Is dynamic SQL the only option?

Comment: "*Is dynamic SQL the only option*" - yes. You will need to create a function that does this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I was also looking for a system catalog that stores the comments, to no avail.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-description.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks. Updating the `pg_description` catalog worked on my system, but I guess this is even more hacky than dynamic SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of such a function:

```
create or replace function comment_on(p_type text, p_object text, p_comment text)
  returns text
as
$$
declare 
  l_sql     text;
  l_comment text;
begin
  l_comment := replace(p_comment, '${created}', 'created at '||to_char(current_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
  l_sql := 'comment on '||p_type||' '||p_object||' is '||quote_literal(l_comment);
  execute l_sql;
  return l_comment;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

You can of course add more placeholders to also support e.g. the current user or similar things (or always append this to the comment regardless of the placeholder):

Note that it lacks any error handling or prevention of SQL injection (but that is probably not a problem).

Usage is like this:

```
create table foo (id integer);
select comment_on('table', 'stuff.foo', '${created} stores bar data');
select comment_on('column', 'stuff.foo.id', 'the id column');
```

The table `foo` will then have the following comment:

```
List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner    |  Size     |              Description
--------+------+-------+----------+-----------+---------------------------------------
 public | foo  | table | postgres | 0 bytes   | created at 2015-10-27 stores bar data
(1 row)
```

And the column will have the following comment:

```
                           Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target |  Description
--------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------------
 id     | integer |           | plain   |              | the id column
```